# Exclude a block from specific parts of the website with the Context module

Tags: blocks

I have a view/block that is showing on the right sidebar. I don't want to show that block on specific parts of the website.

I do know there is the "Show block on specific pages -> All pages except those listed" option where you can put the URL and shouldn't appear, but it does not work.

This Drupal site is using Context to draw the content, so the problem may be there; I think there is another place where I can configure the URLs the same way I explained before on the context, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following steps in Context:

1. Conditions
   Type: Path
   Configuration:

   *

   ~/user
2. Reactions
   Type: Blocks
   Configuration:
   What you want.

The trick is inside the configuration part of Conditions 
With the * you say it should be on all pages and you can exclude path(s) with the ~

Answer (score 0):

The issue to understand is that multiple contexts can be active in parallel. Each context can add it's own block to the theme regions and all works great! But how to define which block comes first in case there are blocks coming from different contexts is an interesting question.