# How to disable a block on a certain view?

Tags: views, blocks

I want to disable two blocks for a certain view. I have tried 
"Show block on specific pages >> All pages except those listed" using the machine name and the view URL with no luck; I tried Drupal Context still no luck. May you please assist?

I have looked at [Exclude a block from specific parts of the website with the Context module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10238/exclude-a-block-from-specific-parts-of-the-website-with-the-context-module), but the answers there didn't help.

These are the details for the view I am using.

- View name: All albums Front
- View machine name: all_albums
- View path: /all-albums
- Website view URL: http://www.example.com/all-albums
- View display name: All Albums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view path is `/all-albums` then try entering `all-albums` in the block under *Show block on specific pages: All pages except those listed*, not the full url or the machine name.

Comment: Kudos, Thank you. I was using /all-albums all along

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use context menu for this thing.It comes out of the box
Here it goes which may help you

Use  "All pages except those listed" and put the view url let say you do not want to show it on view page with url as abc and other view page with url as pqr
,so after selecting " All pages except those listed "  radio option in the text area below it out the both views page url as follows

```
abc
pqr
```

try clearing the cache,though it should not be the reason its not working.