# How to remove block in colorbox?

Tags: nodes, javascript

I'm currently doing recruitment system by using drupal 7..
I want to reduce the user redirect activity, so i've installed the colorbox module and colorbox node module..
I have job vacancy list (in views) which i link the job vacancy (content:title) to the node.
The colorbox work perfect which it can display all the job details..

My problem is the colobox also include all the "block" in my website..

My question is how i want to make the colorbox show only the job details?

Thank you in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the block appearing as part of the view, or just in the Colorbox? If it's just showing in the colorbox, and you go into Structure > Blocks, you should see that "HR Admin" block listed - you can set it to show only on the pages where you want it to appear. You can read about the visibility settings in the [Block documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block). If it is appearing in your view, you may have to give more details for troubleshooting.

This answer may help: [How to disable a block on a certain view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75535/how-to-disable-a-block-on-a-certain-view)

Comment: the block just appear in colorbox only. i have tried to disable the block..and its work..the color box does not show the HR admin block..but i dont want to disable the HR Admin block..